# Macro enabled button VBA

Tags: vba, excel, button

I'm working with VBA macros and I have a macro enabled button of which I want to disable from being clicked when the workbook is first opened. Is there anyway to do this. The macro behind it just leads to another worksheet. ![enter image description here][1]

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: you have to show some code, otherwise nobody can help you..

Comment: Do you mean you have an Excel alert popping up that asks if you want to "Enable Macros"?

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If your button is an ActiveX Command Button, put the following code in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("CommandButton1").Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Change "Sheet1" to reference the sheet that contains the button and change "CommandButton1" to reference the name of the button.